# How to add left and right border between div siblings only

Tags: html, css

In CSS I want to add vertical border between siblings only.  The first div and the last div sibling should not have a vertical border b/c it would be on the ends of the div chain.  How can i do this using css3?

example:

```
<section>
<div>Test1</div>
<div>Test2</div>  
<div>test3</div>
  ...
<div>Testn</div>
</section>
```

css3:

```
section ~ div {
border-left: 1px solid #557;
border-right: 1px solid #557;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
section ~ div {
  border-left: 2px solid #557;
}
section ~ div:first-child {
  border-left: none !important;
}
```

All divs except the first div get a 2px border on their left side;  the first div gets no border on the left side.  Note that for this to work in IE8 and earlier, you'll need to declare a <!DOCTYPE> at the start of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you right, but the first thing to say is that you probably have misunderstand the `~`-notation. With `section ~ div` you are styling all **siblings of section** which are divs. (E.g.: `<section></section><div id="firstSibling"></div>...`)

What you may want to do is something like this:

```
section div:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  border-left: 1px solid #557;
  border-right: 1px solid #557;
}
```

(If I have understand you right)

See also [JsFiddle-Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/zSUy4/)